# Multiple ajax calls after button click

Tags: jquery

I have the following button function which calls **calculate.php** and saves a string that is contained in the `#select-result` div to txt file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sub1" ).click(function() {
    //event.preventDefault();
    var htmlString = $( "#select-result" ).html();    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "calculate.php?raw="+htmlString,
        //data: { 'submit' : true },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("success!");
        }
        });    
    });
});
</script>
```

with html:

```
<div> <button id='sub1'>Submit</button></div>";
```

whenever I click the button I get multiple executions. Any ideas why? If you need more information/code please let me know.

UPDATE:
For some reason once I declared the button in the html and not in thephp function the problem was solved...

I had this:

```
<?php     
    $sql->dl();
?>
```

dl() was:

```
function dl(){
        <span id='select-result'>none </span>
            //notice the button declaration here    
            <button id='sub1'>Submit</button>";


        $query = "SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM t1 order by col1";
        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($c1,$c2,$c3,$c4);
            $stmt->store_result();              

            echo "<ol id='selectable'>";
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<li class='ui-widget-content' name='$t ($p)'>";
                echo $t."</li>".$d;
            }
        echo "</ol></div>";
        }
        $stmt->close();

}
```

When I removed the button from this function and updated the html like this:

```
<button id='sub1'> Submit</button></div>
<?php     
    $sql->dl();
?>
```

The problem was solved.
Any ideas why?
Thanks.

Comment: Consider showing more HTML

Comment: Not sure but may be you have added jquery two times in your page.

Comment: may be there is more than one `$( "#sub1" ).click` or ajax call

Comment: must be a problem with the url, try sending via data: { raw:htmlString }